# Excluding Laravel appends values from model results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, datatables, laravel-datatables

Laravel has the option to add an `$appends` array to each model making additional values automatically available as if they are database attributes by adding accessors for each.

This is normally pretty handy, except in this case I need to ONLY get the fields I put into `select()` because DataTables is expecting only what I send to it.

Example:

```
Item::select(['image', 'name', 'color']);
```

Will return appended fields after `color` in the attributes.

How do I force the exclusion of the appends values when returning results?

Or alternatively, how do I get DataTables to ignore certain attributes?

Not sure which is the least time costly route.

Currently using `yajra/laravel-datatables` package to send data to the jQuery DataTables AJAX request.

Answer (score 3):

You can call each function in the collection object and then use setHidden method to exclude the unwanted fields like this

```
$item= Item::select(['image', 'name', 'color'])->get()->each(function($row){
                    $row->setHidden(['appendedField1', 'appendedField2']);
                });
```

And for the yajra/laravel-datatables you can use something like

```
$item= Item::select(['image', 'name', 'color']);
return Datatables::of($item)->remove_column('appendedField1');
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use `get()` on the results before passing to `yajra/laravel-datatables` package which passes it to the jQuery DataTables package over AJAX. Forgot to mention that package. Otherwise this would be a perfect solution!

Comment: I think you can use remove_column('columnName') method in yajra/laravel-datatables package.

Comment: To solve this I made `$appends` public on my `Item` model, created var `$DT = Datatables::of($items);` and then used `call_user_func_array([$DT, 'removeColumn'], $items->first()->appends);` before returning `make()`. Has to be called this way with `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle` v3 if passing an array.

Comment: Correction, can't do it that way or it messes up pagination. Had to create static method for it which I've posted in a solution. +1 your answer for helping me figure out full solution.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I added this method to my `Item` model:

```
public static function getAppends()
{
    $vars = get_class_vars(__CLASS__);

    return $vars['appends'];
}
```

Then used the following code in the controller:

```
$items = Item::select(['image', 'name', 'color']);

$DT = Datatables::of($items);

call_user_func_array([$DT, 'removeColumn'], Item::getAppends()); // Has to be called this way with yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v3.* if passing an array.

return $DT->make(true);
```